# There's missing space in my partitions on my Macbook 2016

Tags: partition

My Macbook is usually 250gb, and I'm looking to increase the main container disk1 to as close as that as possible. There's like 37GB of unaccounted space. Where is it? I can't tell if its being used or if its potentially something I can merge. Here's a screencap of my current disk list.

[image]

There's only 213.7GB of usable space. To give context this laptop is fairly new, but I may have messed up removing a partition or something. I don't have any data installed either.

[image]

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0`. If Catalina is running already, you have to disable SIP to get the command workin'....

Comment: The output from the commands `diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e Offset -e Size` and `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size` will produce the same information as the `sudo gpt -r show disk0` command without having to disable SIP. However, this only apples if you are using High Sierra or a newer version of macOS.

Comment: Added some additional info. I really appreciate the help even if its any info :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have posted, the missing free space can be found to be between `disk0s1` and `disk0s2`. The macOS operating system is stored in the APFS container partition (`disk0s2`). There is no command or application provided by macOS that can merger this free space back to this container.

```
     byte             byte
starting offset   ending offset    size in bytes   identifer
---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ----------
         24,576      314,597,375      314,572,800  disk0s1
    314,597,376   37,335,146,495   37,020,549,120  free space
 37,335,146,496  251,000,172,543  213,665,026,048  disk0s2
```